# Responsive Navigation Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make my navigation list items scroll when the anchors overflow the screen size of smaller mobile devices. I've tried using overflow-y: auto (and scroll) to fix the issue with no luck. I have tried altering my code to add fixed heights and overflow properties. Any suggestions?

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;    
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #212414;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #DAD38B;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #C2B78F;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 40px;  
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: relative; 
  }
    
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>    
            <a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#my-work">My Work</a>
            <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
            }
            } 
        </script>     
    </nav>
```

Nav Overflow Issue Image is given Below:

[image]

Please help me with fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow: scroll css style only puts a scroll bar when the containing element is not wide or tall enough to display all the information inside of it. This means if a div can only be 200px tall but the content inside needs 300px height to display there would be a scrollbar.

This doesn't apply to your .topnav element because it is tall enough to display the content because it is stretching out passed the height of the screen, meaning the overflow scroll style isn't activated because the div is technically tall enough to display everything even though you can't see it. If you prevent the element from stretching passed the visible screen and stop it from being taller then the height of the screen any content that can't fit would therefore make the style create the scrollbar.

The max-height property in my styles below makes sure that your fixed .topnav element won't ever be taller then the screen size which will make any content that doesn't fit be visible via scrolling.

```
.topnav {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and great explanation! I wasn't familiar with view port units, I'll be using them in my projects from now on.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y: scroll;` will add scrollbar styling to the collapes menu button as well. You need to use `oberflow-y: auto;` along with `max-height: 100vh;` will add the scroll bar for the expanded menu. I added additional menu item in the following snippet for demo purposes.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #212414;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #DAD38B;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #C2B78F;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 40px;  
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: relative; 
  }
    
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>    
            <a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#my-work">My Work</a>
            <a href="#about-me">About Me</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact1</a>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
            }
            } 
        </script>     
    </nav>
```